# style encapsulation on angular custom th component

Tags: css, angular

I am working out a component for a `th` that right now is simply a th with an icon in it:

**custom-th.component.html**

```
<th #main>{{headerName}}<div style="position: relative"><i class="fa fa-th" aria-hidden="true"></i></div></th>
```

**custom-th.component.scss**

```
.fa-th {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: col-resize;
}
```

**custom-th.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-th',
  templateUrl: './custom-th.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-th.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})

export class CustomThComponent{
  @Input('headerName') headerName: string;
  constructor (private renderer: Renderer2) {}


}
```

When I use my custom component in place of another `th` inside of a table like:

```
<thead class="thead-default">
    <tr class="bg-primary">
      <app-custom-th headerName="Key" ></app-custom-th>
      <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

My custom `th` is styled different than the other non-custom th. My understanding of [view encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation) being `none` is that global styles (maybe from other components or bootstrap in my case) can be applied to my host component and its children. If I take the HTML outside of the host component and place it directly into my HTML it works/looks as expected.

**with custom component**
[image]

**custom component's html without using custom component (desired outcome)**
[image]

According to Firefox's inspector, the custom component is about 25x20, so setting 100% width and height does not change anything. If I set width in pixels I get a result, but the cell overall grows much larger (I am not sure why for this).

**firefox inspect**
[image]

Comment: Use attribute selector for your component

Comment: @yurzui, would you mind elaborating? I added an attribute selector, and removed my <th> inside of my component but I have no idea why/how that worked (but it does seem to work).

Comment: Instead of having `selector: 'app-custom-th',` use `selector: [app-custom-th]`

Comment: So your template will look like `<th app-custom-th headerName="Key" ></th>`

Comment: @yurzui , that is what I changed it to, and it works (although I will need to do some more testing), but could you explain why and how that works where the other selector does not work?

Comment: You can't use custom element within `tr` tag only `th,td` etc

Comment: @yurzui, if you post this as an answer with short explanation I will accept it. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [yurzui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5485167/yurzui): You can't use custom elements within a `tr`. But we can have custom components inside of `th` and `td`, so the selector was changed from:

`selector: 'app-custom-th'` to `selector: [app-custom-th]` and the component was then changed to `<th app-custom-th headerName="Key" ></th>`